# Searching for C# or C++ acts like searching for C

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am in the latter phases of productionizing an app that uses azure search.
After many tests I just saw something that I can't figure out.

My indexed data are job descriptions and mostly technical jobs.  When I search for C# or C++ alone I was getting some resumes that were non-technical people that clearly had never done programming before.  So, when I started digging in to it I realized that it's people that have either a middle initial C or something like that in the resume text.

Is there a way to tell azure search that I literally want "C#" or "C++" and not to treat # and ++ as word breaks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no direct to do this. This is something we need to add, it gets in the way particularly in these cases with programming language names.

In the meanwhile, one thing you can do is replace (both at indexing and search time) each with a known string (e.g. C++ -> cplusplus, C# -> csharp). Not the most elegant, but it should help for this case.

Comment: While this is a bummer the workaround is not hard so I'll go with it.  While I have your attention can I put in a thought in to your head that you might be able to pass on to the right people.  The standard tier price for azure search is very high and tough to swallow for startups...

Comment: Regarding your price comment: acknowledged :) we'll be looking at options in the future for this.